# Estilo en archivo PHP

Tags: php

estoy empezando en el php y tengo una pregunta. ¿ Se puede dar estilo al immprimir con eco, quiero poner en negrita una frase y me gustaría hacerlo sin recurrir al css. Es posible? Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tranquilamente puedes asignarle estilo con el atributo **style** así:

```
<?php

$texto = "php <b>html</b> python <span style='color:red; font-weight: bold;'>java</span>";

echo $texto;

?>
```

Como veras puedes colocar negritas con la etiqueta `<b>` ó aplicando el atributo **style** dentro de una etiquta HTML y darle los atributos **css** alli.

Answer (score 0):

Usa la etiqueta strong dentro de ella debe ir el texto que deseas en negrita, las buenas prácticas es hacerlo a través de css.

Answer (score 0):

Claro, hazlo de esta forma:

```
echo "<b>{$variable}</b>";
```

o

```
echo "<b>Hola Mundo!</b>";
```